# RobotFramework : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, robots.txt

Using RobotFramework,

I am trying to retrieve Webelements label  by using FOR loop.

```
${temp}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//*[@class='ui-grid-canvas']
Set Global Variable    ${temp}
${as}    Get Element Count    xpath=//*[@class='ui-grid-canvas']
: FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    ${temp}
\    ${as}=    Get Text    ${ELEMENT}
```

I am getting error at FOR loop. Kindly correct me.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get WebElements is a list, so you should use reference the variable with @ in the for loop:

```py
${temp}=    Get WebElements    xpath=//*[@class='ui-grid-canvas']
Set Global Variable    ${temp}
${as}    Get Element Count    xpath=//*[@class='ui-grid-canvas']
: FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{temp}
\    ${as}=    Get Text    ${ELEMENT}
```